# Is $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1,X-2)$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, integral-domain, polynomial-rings

> Is $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1,X-2)$ an integral domain?

I know I could answer this if I were able to prove that $(X^2+Y^2-1,X-2)$ is a prime ideal (or not) or if i could prove that this is isomorphic to some other domain (tbh, i think it isn't).

Either way, I don't know where to start.

Any tips are appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: here's a hint. can you see what $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x-2)$ is isomorphic to?

Comment: To start with, you could consider mod out by $(x-2)$ and then use the third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[y]$ right? Since $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x-2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Koro So $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1,x-2)$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2+3)$?

Comment: yep, that's right :) (on both counts)

Comment: and now can you see what $\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2+3)$ is isomorphic to?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I believe the elements of $\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2+3)$ are the polynomials of deggre at most 1, so it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom wait, i think i'm mistaken. $y$ should go to $\sqrt{-3}$ so this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ instead, right?

Comment: that is exactly right! :) (your second comment I mean – the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X-2)\simeq\mathbb{R}[Y]$ and $(X^2+Y^2-1)/(X-2)\simeq(Y^2+3)$.

By the third homomorphism theorem, we have $$\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X-2)}{(X^2+Y^2-1)/(X-2)}\simeq \mathbb{R}[Y]/(Y^2+3)$$

In addition to that, $(Y^2+3)$ is the kernel of the surjective homomorphism $$\varphi:R[Y]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$
$$Y\mapsto i\sqrt{3}$$

So, by the first homomorphism theorem, $\mathbb{R}[Y]/(Y^2+3)\simeq\mathbb{C}$. And we conclude that $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1,X-2)$ is a field, since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, hence it's an integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$ then $R/I$ is an integral domain